# Enable one object in a disabled tabWidget in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, webview, tabs, widget

In my project I have made a tabWidget the centralWidget for my program. When the program is first opened by the user, the tabWidget is disabled. The user can enable everything when they open a file. So everything in my program starts disabled.

In one of the tabs, I have a webView widget that plays a youtube video set to autoplay. Everything works fine, except the webView can't be clicked (the video can't be stopped) until the tabWidget is enabled.

Is there any way I can allow ONE object to be enabled while everything else is still disabled?

It's hard for me to explain, but here is a picture:

[image]

As you can see, everything is disabled including the video. Can I single out that video to be enabled?

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no free lunch. You have two options:

1. Disable the other tabs and all other widgets on the Settings tab.
2. Make the webView widget a popup child of the main window (and then manage geometry on size/location changes of main window).

I suppose a third option would be to have another enabled tab that contains the video and widgets to open the file. This would help the user know what to do rather than assaulting them with a disabled interface.